# is a php websocket xss attackable?

Tags: php

It might be a silly question but for a php websockets chat, is it possible for a server or a client be victim of a XSS attack ?

If so, what if the server require a prefix like:

> /say Hello World!

Is it a good idea to use preg_match to check for the /say prefix and htmlSpecialChars to filter the message string ?

Answer (score 1):

**Any** system, regardless of underlying tech, that displays user input in an HTML page is potentially XSSable. Yes, you need something like `htmlspecialchars()` on messages.